# Change value color if negative result

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I want to change value color to red on my page if the value is negative.I get my values from my DB so perhaps I need to use jQuery or some if else statement in my cshtml.If you know some answers I would apriciate it, thx in advance! Here is my details page..

```
@model ParentDbModel
@{
    PageNavigation nav = ViewBag.PageNavigation as PageNavigation;
}
<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">


       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PAYINPAYOUT, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <b>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PAYINPAYOUTCONVERTED)
            </b>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PAYINPAYOUT)
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

so, if this (PAYINPAYOUTCONVERTED) has negative value it has to be painted in red!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use conditional operator `?:`

```
<b style="color:@(Model.PAYINPAYOUTCONVERTED<0?"red":"")">
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PAYINPAYOUTCONVERTED)
</b>
```